# How to calculate log determinant of an Armadillo sparse matrix efficiently

Tags: eigen, rcpp, armadillo

I'm trying to write an MCMC procedure using RcppArmadillo which involves computing log determinants of some around 30,000 x 30,000 sparse matrices. It seems that log_det() in Armadillo does not support sp_mat right now so I'm doing something like this:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
using namespace arma;

double eigen_ldet(sp_mat arma_mat) {
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> eigen_s = Rcpp::as<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>(Rcpp::wrap(arma_mat));
  Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> solver;
  solver.compute(eigen_s);
  double det = solver.logAbsDeterminant();
  return det;
}
```

I feel it is really crappy and slow. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:
Here is the mockup:

```
library(Matrix)

m_mat = function(i = 1688, j = 18, rho = 0.5, alp = 0.5){
  w1 = matrix(runif(i^2),nrow = i, ncol = i)
  w2 = matrix(runif(j^2),nrow = j, ncol = j)
  w1 = w1/rowSums(w1)
  w2 = w2/rowSums(w2)
  diag(w1) = 0
  diag(w2) = 0
  w1 = diag(i) - rho*w1
  w2 = diag(j) - alp*w2
  w1 = kronecker(Matrix(diag(j)), w1)
  w2 = kronecker(Matrix(diag(i)), w2)
  ind = matrix(c(rep(seq(1,i), each = j), rep(seq(1,j),i)), ncol = 2)
  w2 = cbind(ind, w2)
  w2 = w2[order(w2[,2]),]
  w2 = t(w2[, -c(1,2)])
  w2 = cbind(as.matrix(ind), w2)
  w2 = w2[order(w2[,2]),]
  w2 = t(w2[, -c(1,2)])
  return(w1 + w2)
}
```

Edit2: Here is the second mockup with a sparse w1:

```
m_mat2 = function(i = 1688, j = 18, nb = 4, range = 10, rho = 0.5, alp = 0.5){
  w1 = Matrix(0, nrow = i, ncol = i)
  for ( h in 1:i){
   rnd = as.integer(rnorm(nb, h, range))
   rnd = ifelse(rnd > 0 & rnd <=  i, rnd, h)
   rnd = unique(rnd)
   w1[h, rnd] = 1
  }
  w1 = w1/rowSums(w1)
  w2 = matrix(runif(j^2),nrow = j, ncol = j)
  w2 = w2/rowSums(w2)
  diag(w1) = 0
  diag(w2) = 0
  w1 = diag(i) - rho*w1
  w2 = diag(j) - alp*w2
  w1 = kronecker(Matrix(diag(j)), w1)
  w2 = kronecker(Matrix(diag(i)), w2)
  ind = matrix(c(rep(seq(1,i), each = j), rep(seq(1,j),i)), ncol = 2)
  w2 = cbind(ind, w2)
  w2 = w2[order(w2[,2]),]
  w2 = t(w2[, -c(1,2)])
  w2 = cbind(as.matrix(ind), w2)
  w2 = w2[order(w2[,2]),]
  w2 = t(w2[, -c(1,2)])
  return(w1 + w2)
}
```

An actual sparse w1 case should be much more irregular, but it takes about the same time to calculate (by the above code) the determinant of this one as using an actual w1.

Comment: How sparse is your matrix? Can you provide code for generating a random matrix that is similar to your real problem?

Comment: Sounds like an upstream issue for Armadillo so maybe once you have a small mock example consider filing a GitHub (or GitLab) issue?

Comment: This isn't really possible due to the `arma::sp_mat` accessors for the necessary `Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<T >>` construction being MIA.

Comment: That's weird because it works on my PC

Comment: Your sample matrix has a peculiar pattern: 18 x 18 matrices of size 1688 x 1688. The 18 diagonal matrices are densely filled. All other matrices have only the diagonal set. Is that representative for your real problem? If yes, then [`Eigen::SparseLU`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicSparseSystems.html) might be suboptimal: "optimized for small and large problems with irregular patterns".

Comment: @wjyzxcv I was emphasizing that this needs to go through the hashing into a `dgCmatrix` and then back. There is no direct way to access the required elements to map the memory into `Eigen` from `Armadillo` (though the reverse is currently possible.)

Comment: @Ralf Stubner In some cases the diagonal matrices can be sparse (actually the one I'm currently working on is very sparse) but this one is more general. I'm new to sparse matrices and don't really know how to deal with the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

From my experiments I find that the conversion from Armadillo to Eigen matrix is quite fast. Most of the time is spent in `solver.compute()`. I do not know if there are any faster algorithms to determine the log determinant of a sparse matrix, but I have found an approximation that is at least applicable to your mock-up: Only use the (dense) block-diagonal (see e.g. [here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ipsen/ps/slides_iwasep.pdf) for ways to include other parts of the matrix). If an approximate solution is sufficient, this is quite good and fast:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <Rcpp/Benchmark/Timer.h>
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double arma_sldet(sp_mat arma_mat, int blocks, int size) {
  double ldet = 0.0;
  double val = 0.0;
  double sign = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < blocks; ++i) {
    int begin = i * size;
    int end = (i + 1) * size - 1;
    sp_mat sblock = arma_mat.submat(begin, begin, end, end);
    mat dblock(sblock);
    log_det(val, sign, dblock);
    ldet += val;
  }
  return ldet;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List eigen_ldet(sp_mat arma_mat) {
  Rcpp::Timer timer;
  timer.step("start");
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> eigen_s = Rcpp::as<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>(Rcpp::wrap(arma_mat));
  timer.step("conversion");
  Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> solver;
  solver.compute(eigen_s);
  timer.step("solver");
  double det = solver.logAbsDeterminant();
  timer.step("log_det");
  Rcpp::NumericVector res(timer);
  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("log_det") = det,
                            Rcpp::Named("timer") = res);
}

/*** R
library(Matrix)

m_mat = function(i = 1688, j = 18, rho = 0.5, alp = 0.5){
  w1 = matrix(runif(i^2),nrow = i, ncol = i)
  w2 = matrix(runif(j^2),nrow = j, ncol = j)
  w1 = w1/rowSums(w1)
  w2 = w2/rowSums(w2)
  diag(w1) = 0
  diag(w2) = 0
  w1 = diag(i) - rho*w1
  w2 = diag(j) - alp*w2
  w1 = kronecker(Matrix(diag(j)), w1)
  w2 = kronecker(Matrix(diag(i)), w2)
  ind = matrix(c(rep(seq(1,i), each = j), rep(seq(1,j),i)), ncol = 2)
  w2 = cbind(ind, w2)
  w2 = w2[order(w2[,2]),]
  w2 = t(w2[, -c(1,2)])
  w2 = cbind(as.matrix(ind), w2)
  w2 = w2[order(w2[,2]),]
  w2 = t(w2[, -c(1,2)])
  return(w1 + w2)
}
m <- m_mat(i = 200)
system.time(eigen <- eigen_ldet(m))
system.time(arma <- arma_sldet(m, 18, 200))
diff(eigen$timer)/1000000
all.equal(eigen$log_det, arma)
m <- m_mat()
#eigen_ldet(m) # takes to long ...
system.time(arma <- arma_sldet(m, 18, 1688))
*/
```

Results for a smaller mock-up:

```
> m <- m_mat(i = 200)

> system.time(eigen <- eigen_ldet(m))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.703   0.049   3.751 

> system.time(arma <- arma_sldet(m, 18, 200))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.059   0.012   0.019 

> diff(eigen$timer)/1000000
 conversion      solver     log_det 
   5.208586 3738.131168    0.582578 

> all.equal(eigen$log_det, arma)
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.002874847"
```

The approximate solution is very close and much faster. We also see the timing distribution for the exact solution.

Results for the full mock-up:

```
> m <- m_mat()

> #eigen_ldet(m) # takes to long ...
> system.time(arma <- arma_sldet(m, 18, 1688))
   user  system elapsed 
  5.965   2.529   2.578
```

An even faster approximation can be achieved when only considering the diagonal:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double arma_sldet_diag(sp_mat arma_mat) {
  vec d(arma_mat.diag());
  return sum(log(d));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. I apologize for not making it clear that how a small change in rho/alp effects the determinant is crucial in the metropolis algorithm. This approximation does not take alp into account so I can't use it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have plenty of memory on your machine (say 32+ Gb), and a fast implementation of LAPACK (example: OpenBLAS or Intel MKL), a quick and dirty way is to convert the sparse matrix into a dense matrix, and compute the log determinant on the dense matrix.

Example:

```
sp_mat X = sprandu(30000,30000,0.01);

cx_double log_result = log_det( mat(X) );
```

While this obviously takes lots of memory, the advantage is that it avoids time consuming sparse solvers / factorizations. OpenBLAS or MKL will also take advantage of multiple cores.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not a good solution. I do use MKL but the sparse solver is still much faster, and I need to deal with much larger sparse matrices in the future it won't be viable.